# How to fix avd emulator process killed?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, avd-manager

I am new to Android Development and I ran across this issue while building Flutter apps.
Every time I try to run a previously initialized Android Virtual Device I get a dialogue box saying: "Emulator process for AVD{name} was killed."
What Happens:

1. AVD runs fine if I create a fresh device. It runs fine.
2. If I restart my computer and run the AVD again, it starts to show the error.
3. If I close AVD and android studio and re-run the AVD without restarting, it runs fine.

I checked the logs and here is what I found:

> Emulator: Failed to open /qemu.conf, err: 2

I have enough space in my disk, so that cannot be the issue.

If it matters I have Valorant installed and there is a dialogue box saying that it is not compatible with android studio. I have it set to disabled on startup so I don't think Volarant is an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the issue.
Apparently setting the navigation method of the AVD to gesture causes this problem. If it is set to 3 button navigation, the issue is fixed.